# InterstitialAd is not recognized as a class of Android Studio and libgdx

Tags: android, libgdx, admob, google-play-services, interstitial

I would like to add interstitial ads to my application , and I have done the following:

**1**. `File -> Project Structure -> Ads`: i have flag `adMob`

**2**. my gradle.build:

```
project(":android") {
    apply plugin: "android"
    apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'

    configurations { natives }

    dependencies {
        compile project(":core")
        compile "com.badlogicgames.gdx:gdx-backend-android:$gdxVersion"
        natives "com.badlogicgames.gdx:gdx-platform:$gdxVersion:natives-armeabi"
        natives "com.badlogicgames.gdx:gdx-platform:$gdxVersion:natives-armeabi-v7a"
        natives "com.badlogicgames.gdx:gdx-platform:$gdxVersion:natives-x86"
        compile "com.badlogicgames.gdx:gdx-box2d:$gdxVersion"
        natives "com.badlogicgames.gdx:gdx-box2d-platform:$gdxVersion:natives-armeabi"
        natives "com.badlogicgames.gdx:gdx-box2d-platform:$gdxVersion:natives-armeabi-v7a"
        natives "com.badlogicgames.gdx:gdx-box2d-platform:$gdxVersion:natives-x86"
        compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:8.4.0'
    }
}
```

**3**. i have add the code from [this tutorial](http://www.norakomi.com/tutorial_admob_part2_interstitial_ads.php)

but i have the problem...when i add the library, don't work....:
[image]

I do not add the libraries to recognize the class ... how do I fix ?

Answer (score 1):

Try adding the following:

```
dependencies {
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-ads:8.4.0'
}
```

to the bottom of `build.gradle` file in the **android** project (*not* the one under **core** project).

Comment: your solution you set as you say when you click on AdMob ( point 1 )

Comment: @Mr.Developer i don't understand your comment. Does the above dependency appear in android's `gradle`?

Comment: I mean that when I make the point in the first question I posted , or add admob ... this means that sect addiction as you say ... so you have already done what tips in Gradle Android . :)